# Where did they have the Chosson's Tisch in Europe?

Tags: wedding

In Europe when they didn't make chasunahs in a hall and instead made chasunahs in private homes or in some open area in the town where did they make the chosson's Tisch? Was the whole procedure of writing the Kesuvah and the eidim signing done in front of guests like it is today? Or was it not done elaborately like today and instead just done in a corner of the house somewhere?

Comment: Some communities sign the Ketuba under the Chuppa.

Comment: `hen they didn't make chasunahs in a hall and instead made chasunahs in private homes or in some open area in the town` Source?

Comment: @mevaqesh - Some Ashkenazim (not Yekkes, I believe) will not hold a chassoneh in a shul because the Christian practice is to hold weddings in houses of worship. Therefore, most weddings are done in a courtyard outside.

Comment: @EzraHoerster While some individuals may choose to make a wedding in a courtyard, the practice of avoiding weddings in synagogues, in no way requires a wedding in a courtyard. | The lack of sources in the question that weddings actually took place in the courtyard, or private homes, therefore remains.

Comment: @mevaqesh. Sources are my great-grandmother. My chavrusa's grandfather. My uncle's grandmother and her neighbor. The wedding photos from my rebbi's father's chasuna.

Comment: (re your comment) I recommend you edit that info in to the question, so people believe you. Comments are ephemeral by design.

Comment: @msh210. It's not really part of the question that I asked. What would it help if I added into the question the fact that I heard it from my great-grandmother?

Comment: "I know X from my forebears. What's with this detail of X?" is always stronger than "What's with this detail of X?" in my opinion. The latter will just make people say "Maybe X isn't even true." and move on.